# Google Geocoding API. I have a problem with parsing json response

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a problem with parsing json response. My error is: [__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. As I see the params should be NSDictionary. Why does the params is an NSArray?

```
enter code hereNSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
NSString* requestStatus = [dictionary objectForKeyNotNull:@"status"];
if ([requestStatus isEqualToString:@"OK"])
{
    NSDictionary *params = [dictionary objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSString *addresses = [params objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];
}`enter code here`
```

My json is :

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "1600",
      "short_name": "1600",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 37.4219720,
        "lng": -122.0841430
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 37.4188244,
          "lng": -122.0872906
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 37.4251196,
          "lng": -122.0809954
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For @"results" key you have an array.

So you need

`NSString *addresses = [[params objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];`